# Equation/ sorting to separate one long column of data into separate columns

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two columns of data in an excel spreadsheet that is listed like, each date has three numbers associated with it. It is shown like this:

- 1  112
- 1  123
- 1  456
- 2  788
- 2  989
- 2  901

What I am trying to do is have the data shown like this:

- 1
- 112
- 123
- 456

Then in another column next to it have;

- 2
- 788
- 989
- 901

Comment: Welcome to SO. FYI, SO does NOT provide code writing service. So pls check [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, I do not think that helps me with the problem that I have. @ManishChristian

Comment: The link will help you on **`How to ask good question`** which you didn't. That being said, show us what have you tried so far, what is the issue and we'll be happy to help you with your issue/s.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this can be done pretty easily/quickly.

First, select your entire column that has `# ###` and go to Data --> Text to Columns, and choose “Delimited”, then use a “Space” delimiter.  This will separate your numbers by the space, so `1` and `2` will be in Column A, and the three digit numbers are in B (or wherever you decide to put them).

Then, just get the unique values from column A.  I tend to copy the entire column to a temporary column (or worksheet), then highlight them and go to Data --> Remove Duplicates.  Now you have a list of unique numbers.  Copy and paste these (transposing) into (for example) column D.

Then, in D2, enter this formula (adjust ranges as necessary) as an array, using <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6=D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$6)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$2:$B2))),"")`

Here’s a screenshot of the final output:
[image]